algorithm using recursive function
https://codeup.kr/problem.php?id=6098
Hi, Dear!
I ask your precious advice..
Thank you in advice
[Rule : Problem Statement]

start point : (1,1)
Only move to 0
Must move right(0,1) or down(1,0)
(* Moving right is always preferred over moving down)
Move until meeting 2 or being unable to move to any direction
Mark the path passed with 9

I expected A output, but My code printed wrong output, B. I don't know why..
In detail, I expected the 'break' to work in (6,6), but it didn't. After going over (7,6), all zero is finally changed to 9. It is wrong result... In other words, the third 'elif' is not working.
Please let me know how to fix..
[A]  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 9 9 1 0 0 0 0 0 1  
1 0 9 1 1 1 0 0 0 1  
1 0 9 9 9 9 9 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 9 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 9 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 9 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  

[B]  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 9 9 1 9 9 9 9 9 1  
1 0 9 1 1 1 9 9 9 1  
1 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 9 1  
1 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 9 1  
1 9 9 9 9 1 9 1 9 1  
1 9 9 9 9 1 9 1 9 1  
1 9 9 9 9 1 9 9 9 1  
1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 1  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[Initial grid]  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

[output; In fact, It should stop in (6,6)]
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1  
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 1  
1 2  
2 2  
3 2  
3 3  
3 4  
3 5  
3 6  
4 6  
5 6  
6 6  
7 6  
7 7  
7 8  
8 8  
8 8  
7 8  
8 7  
7 7  
8 7  
7 8  
8 6  
6 7  
6 8  
7 8  
8 8  
6 8  
7 6 
8 6  
7 7  
8 6  
4 7  
4 8  
5 8  
6 8  
7 8  
8 8  
5 8  
6 8  
7 8  
8 8  
4 8  
5 6  
6 6  
7 6  
8 6  
3 7  
3 8  
4 8  
5 8  
6 8  
7 8  
8 8  
3 8  
4 6  
5 6  
6 6  
7 6  
8 6  
3 6  
4 5  
5 5  
6 5  
7 5  
8 5  
7 6  
8 5  
3 5  
4 5  
5 5  
6 5  
7 5  
8 5  
3 6  
4 4  
5 4  
6 4  
7 4  
8 4  
7 5  
8 4  
6 5  
7 4  
8 4  
5 5  
6 4  
7 4  
8 4  
4 5  
5 4  
6 4  
7 4  
8 4  
3 4  
4 4  
5 4  
6 4  
7 4  
8 4  
3 5  
4 3  
5 3  
6 3  
7 3  
8 3  
7 4  
8 3  
6 4  
7 3  
8 3  
5 4  
6 3  
7 3  
8 3  
4 4  
5 3  
6 3  
7 3  
8 3  
3 3  
4 3  
5 3  
6 3  
7 3  
8 3  
3 4  
4 2  
5 2  
6 2  
7 2  
8 2  
7 3  
8 2  
6 3  
7 2  
8 2  
5 3  
6 2  
7 2  
8 2  
4 3  
5 2  
6 2  
7 2  
8 2  
2 3  
3 2  
4 2  
5 2  
6 2  
7 2  
8 2  
3 3  
4 2  
5 2  
6 2  
7 2  
8 2  
1 3  
1 4  
1 5  
1 6  
1 7  
1 8  
2 8  
3 8  
4 8  
5 8  
6 8  
7 8  
8 8  
2 8  
3 8  
4 8  
5 8  
6 8  
7 8  
8 8  
1 8  
2 7  
3 7    
4 7  
5 7  
6 7  
7 7  
8 7  
1 7  
2 7  
3 7  
4 7  
5 7  
6 7  
7 7  
8 7  
1 8  
2 6  
3 6  
4 6  
5 6  
6 6  
7 6  
8 6  
1 6  
2 6  
3 6  
4 6  
5 6  
6 6  
7 6  
8 6  
1 7  
2 5  
3 5  
4 5  
5 5  
6 5  
7 5  
8 5  
1 5  
2 4  
3 4  
4 4  
5 4  
6 4  
7 4  
8 4  
1 4  
2 2  
3 2  
4 2  
5 2  
6 2  
7 2  
8 2  
1 2  
2 1  
3 1  
4 1  
5 1  
6 1  
7 1  
8 1  
7 2  
8 1  
6 2  
7 1  
8 1  
5 2  
6 1  
7 1  
8 1  
4 2  
5 1  
6 1  
7 1  
8 1  
3 2  
4 1  
5 1  
6 1  
7 1  
8 1  
2 2  
3 1  
4 1  
5 1  
6 1  
7 1  
8 1  

[My Code]
grid = []
for i in range(10):
  grid.append([])
  for j in range(10):
    grid[i].append(0)

for i in range(10):
  grid[i] = list(map(int, input().split()))

p_x, p_y = (1,1)
grid[p_x][p_y] = 9

def move(p_x, p_y):
  for x in range(p_x,9):
    for y in range(p_y,9):
      print(x,y)

      if grid[x][y + 1] == 0:
        grid[x][y + 1] = 9
        move(x, y + 1)
      elif grid[x][y + 1] == 2:
        grid[x][y + 1] = 9
        break
      elif grid[x + 1][y] == 0:
        grid[x + 1][y] = 9
        move(x + 1, y)
      elif grid[x + 1][y] == 2:
        grid[x + 1][y] = 9
        break
      else:
        break
  
move(p_x, p_y)



Please explain the logic behind the expected result.

What is your question?

@deceze I added the logic. Thanks!

I don't know why all zero is changed to 9. I expected A as result. In order to do that, code shoud stop to work in (6,6), but it isn't. @MUYBelgium

Can you provide the problem statement in English?

I wrote the problem statement above~ I'll let you know if you tell me what part you think that the explanation is insufficient about. @Unmitigated

@유한정 It's unclear when moving down is allowed.

@ The moving is allowed when 0. Also, the moving is allowed only to right or down. I have just found my mistake, so I corrected the error ( 'left' -> 'down'). @Unmitigated

@유한정 Is a move right always preferred over a move down when both are possible?

@Unmitigated Sorry, I missed that point. Moving right is always preferred over moving down.

Instead of iterating over the x and y values in a particular range, just try each move in order and make a recursive call to move for the next location, which keeps track of the current location correctly.
def move(p_x, p_y):
    for dx in range(2):
        if grid[p_x + dx][p_y + 1 - dx] == 2:
            grid[p_x + dx][p_y + 1 - dx] = 9
            break
        elif grid[p_x + dx][p_y + 1 - dx] == 0:
            grid[p_x + dx][p_y + 1 - dx] = 9
            return move(p_x + dx, p_y + 1 - dx)

It will be more efficient to rewrite this with iteration.

Thanks a lot ! Do you happen to let me know why my code is working wrong. (why my 'break' is not working) ..? @Unmitigated

@유한정 You would need to break twice to exit two layers of for loops. Also, it isn't clear why you're looping over all those positions instead of just checking the two possible moves.

Some issues:
You're mixing iteration and recursion, so that even when you have found a solution path via an inner call of move(), the execution still continues the loop in which that move() call was made. You should "get out of there" ;-)
Also, the break statements only break out of the inner loop, not out of the outer loop. By consequence you'll continue writing more 9s in the grid when you already found the target.
But as you use recursion, you should not need to iterate over different values of x and y. Only the alternative move (going down instead of right) should be considered.
Now, for the given grid, you can "greedily" look for a good path, but that might not be true for other grids, like this one:
grid = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]

For that you need to implement backtracking, i.e. when a recursive call could not make its way to the target, try the alternative move with another recursive call:
def move(x, y):
    if grid[x][y] != 0:  # not free 
        return grid[x][y] == 2  # True if it is the target
    grid[x][y] = 9  # visit
    for x1, y1 in ((x, y + 1), (x + 1, y)):
        if move(x1, y1) :
            return True  # Propagate the success back to the caller
    grid[x][y] = 0  # Apparently the wrong way, so undo (backtrack)

p_x, p_y = (1, 1)
# don't mark with 9 yet here.
if move(p_x, p_y):  # Found a path!
    for row in grid:
        print(row)
else:
    print("No path found.")


Nice answer. OP probably meant to write grid[y][x], not grid[x][y]. I added a post that shows how to modify your move program to enumerate all solutions.

Addendum to @trincot's answer. You could easily modify move to enumerate all possible solutions for the given starting point -
def move(x, y):
    try:
        match grid[y][x]:
            case 2:
                yield # solution found
            case 0:
                grid[y][x] = 9  # visit
                yield from move(x, y + 1)
                yield from move(x, y - 1)
                yield from move(x + 1, y)
                yield from move(x - 1, y)
                grid[y][x] = 0  # unvisit
    except IndexError:
        pass

Now move produces an iterable result instead of a simple True or False. Run the program to see all 131 solutions -
for (n, _) in enumerate(move(1, 1)):
    print(f"solution {n}")
    for row in grid:
        print(row)

